# My laravel livewire create form keeps giving me errors

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-livewire, laravel-9

**LONG POST WARNING**

why isn't my form to create a new user not working? im using laravel 9 and livewire. This is my code:

this is the button from where i show the model to create a form:

```
<div class="py-4 space-y-4">
            <div class="flex justify-between px-2">
                <div class="w-1/4">
                    <x-jet-input  placeholder="search will go here"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <x-jet-button wire:click="create">New Skill</x-jet-button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the model that shows the form. this model is also used to edit a skill as per Caleb the livewire creator:

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="save">
        <x-jet-dialog-modal wire:model.defer="showEditModal">
            <x-slot name="title">Edit Skill</x-slot>

            <x-slot name="content">
                <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
                    <x-jet-label for="name" value="{{ __('Skill name') }}" />
                    <select wire:model="editing.name"
                            id="name"
                            type="text"
                            class="mt-1 block w-full border-gray-300
                             focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring
                              focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50
                               rounded-md shadow-sm">
                        @foreach(\App\Models\Skill::LANGUAGES as $value => $label)
                            <option value="{{ $value }}">{{ $label }}</option>
                        @endforeach

                    </select>
                        <x-jet-input-error for="editing.name" class="mt-2" />
                        <x-jet-label for="years" value="{{ __('Years of experience') }}" class="mt-4"/>
                        <x-jet-input wire:model="editing.years" id="years" type="number"
                             min="{{\App\Models\Skill::MIN_YEARS_OF_EXPERIENCE}}"
                             max="{{\App\Models\Skill::MAX_YEARS_OF_EXPERIENCE}}"
                         class="mt-1 block w-full"
                         placeholder="Years of experience"/>
                        <x-jet-input-error for="editing.years" class="mt-2" />
                </div>
            </x-slot>

            <x-slot name="footer">
                <x-jet-secondary-button wire:click="$set('showEditModal', false)" class="mr-2">Cancel</x-jet-secondary-button>
                <x-jet-button type="submit">Save</x-jet-button>
            </x-slot>
        </x-jet-dialog-modal>
    </form>
```

And this is my livewire component:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Skill;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Livewire\Component;


class Skills extends Component
{
    public $name ='';
    public $showEditModal = false;
    public Skill $editing;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'editing.name' => 'required|in:'.collect(Skill::LANGUAGES)->keys()->implode(','),
            'editing.years' => 'required|numeric|between:' . Skill::MIN_YEARS_OF_EXPERIENCE . ',' . Skill::MAX_YEARS_OF_EXPERIENCE,
        ];
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.skills', [
            'skills' => Skill::where('user_id', auth()->id())->get(),
        ]);
    }

    public function mount(){
        $this->editing = $this->makeBlankSkill();
    }

    public function makeBlankSkill(){
        return Skill::make([
         'name' => 'javascript', 
         'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        ]);
    }

    public function create(){
        if ($this->editing->getKey()) $this->editing = $this->makeBlankSkill();
        $this->showEditModal = true;
    }

    public function edit(Skill $skill) {
        if ($this->editing->isNot($skill)) $this->editing = $skill;
        $this->showEditModal = true;
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $this->validate();
        $this->editing->save();
        $this->showEditModal = false;
    }
}
```

I keep getting SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value and i dont know why.

This is my modal:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Skill extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    const DEFAULT_OPTION = 'Please select a skill';

    const LANGUAGES = [
        'javascript' => 'JavaScript',
        'php' => 'PHP',
        'python' => 'Python',
        'java' => 'Java',
        'c#' => 'C#',
        'c++' => 'C++',
        'ruby' => 'Ruby',
        'swift' => 'Swift',
        'typescript' => 'TypeScript',
        'rust' => 'Rust',
        'go' => 'Go',
        'kotlin' => 'Kotlin',
        'scala' => 'Scala',
        'dart' => 'Dart',
        'r' => 'R',
        'perl' => 'Perl',
        'elixir' => 'Elixir',
        'clojure' => 'Clojure',
        'haskell' => 'Haskell',
        'erlang' => 'Erlang',
        'lisp' => 'Lisp',
        'sql' => 'SQL',
        'bash' => 'Bash',
        'laravel' => 'Laravel',
        'symfony' => 'Symfony',
        'codeigniter' => 'CodeIgniter',
        'yii' => 'Yii',
        'zend' => 'Zend',
        'cakephp' => 'CakePHP',
        'fuelphp' => 'FuelPHP',
        'slim' => 'Slim',
        'lumen' => 'Lumen',
        'phalcon' => 'Phalcon',
        'silex' => 'Silex',
        'express' => 'Express',
        'koa' => 'Koa',
        'hapi' => 'Hapi',
        'meteor' => 'Meteor',
        'angular' => 'Angular',
        'ember' => 'Ember',
        'react' => 'React',
        'vue' => 'Vue',
        'backbone' => 'Backbone',
        'd3' => 'D3',
        'threejs' => 'Three.js',
        ];

    const MIN_YEARS_OF_EXPERIENCE = 1;
    const MAX_YEARS_OF_EXPERIENCE = 50;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'user_id', 'years'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appriceated

I've done all there is to do.At least i hope. I've added the

```
$illable
```

array ive set the

```
'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
```

Not sure what else im missing

Comment: I’m noticing strange things in your view, doesn’t make much sense. Is `auth()->user()->id` returning the id of the authenticated user?

Comment: no im trying to set the user_id as the id of the authenticated user. user_id is also a foreign key

Comment: Yes I know, but does `auth()->id()` or `auth()->user()->id` output the id of the currently authenticated user or does it output `null`, that’s the question

Comment: thats what im trying to figure out.any idea how to do that because ive been in front of the computer for hours now and at this point im straight up lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public function save()
{
    $this->validate();
    $user = auth()->user();
    $this->editing->user_id = $user->id;
    $this->editing->save();
    $this->showEditModal = false;
}
```

This was the answer for me

Answer (score 0):

If `user_id` is `null` when creating a new Skill, this means there is no authenticated user. You can simply check by doing `dd(auth()->id())`. If you're logged in, this will return the primary key for your authentication model. If this is empty, you're simply not authenticated, and so you must first log in.

In the case your `user_id` is actually set, but it isn't arriving in your database upon saving, you'll have to check if the property `user_id` is correctly set on the Skill model's `protected $fillable` property.

<strike>If you `dd($this->editing)` right after mount, you can check the attributes of the model, and if the `user_id` is set, you know the error happens when saving to the database.</strike>

As it turns out, Livewire won't hydrate newly set properties on models. This is because Livewire "rehydrates" the models by simply re-fetching them from the database. This can be solved defining a `rules` property [as shown here](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#binding-models), directly relating to the model properties. This would ensure Livewire keeps the state of the updated properties.

Comment: yes its returning the id. also i failed to mention that im using laravel jetstream so i dont think being authenticated would be an issue since everything is being executed after the user is logged in

Comment: also my phpstorm is showing an error saying the `user_id` column wasn't found, in my `render()` function `'skills' => Skill::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get(),` but the column is there

Comment: i switched the `make` method with the `create` method but now it submits the form when page loads and doesn't give me a chance to enter the input data

Comment: @kristitanellari I updated my answer to cover more cases. You shouldn't use `create` because your component isn't written to work like that. You're certain the `user_id` column is present in your database?

Comment: id did dd($this->editing) on the `mount` function right after `$this->editing = $this->makeBlankSkill();` and this is what i got on page reload  on the `#attributes` section `  #attributes: array:3 [▼ "user_id" => 1 "name" => "" "years" => null ]` and on the `#fillable` section `  #fillable: array:3 [▼ 0 => "name" 1 => "user_id" 2 => "years" ]` . So the `user_id ` is being passed on. just dont know why isnt being passed on after i submit the modal.

Comment: Ok so i did `dd($this->editing)` on the `save()` method and the `user_id` isn't  being passed on when the `save()` method is fired. Any idea on how to deal with that?

Comment: @kristitanellari I've edited my answer another time, as I now know what's happening. Glad your issue is solved, however.

Comment: yes sir and thank you for your insight as that was the reason that led me to close in on the problem and solving it. Appreciate the help. @Yinci